# OpenVPN client blocks incoming external connections

Tags: networking, openvpn

An OpenVPN connection *(a Linux-like homebrew package on macOS)* to my office works flawlessly, but it blocks incoming HTTP(S) traffic from my external IP address; however, when I turn off OpenVPN, I can access my computer from outside, otherwise it is blocked.

How can I configure OpenVPN to allow incoming connections over ports 80 and 443, as if there were no VPN?

- Client config:

  ```ini
  client

  dev tun
  proto udp
  remote my-server-1 1194

  resolv-retry infinite
  nobind
  persist-key
  persist-tun

  ca ca.crt
  cert client.crt
  key client.key
  remote-cert-tls server
  tls-auth ta.key 1
  cipher AES-256-CBC

  verb 3
  ```
- Server config

  ```ini
  port 1194
  proto udp
  dev tun

  ca ca.crt
  cert server.crt
  key server.key  
  dh dh2048.pem

  server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
  ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

  keepalive 10 120

  tls-auth ta.key 0 
  cipher AES-256-CBC

  persist-key
  persist-tun

  status openvpn-status.log
  verb 3

  explicit-exit-notify 1
  ```
- Output of `netstat -rn` without VPN:

  ```ini
  Internet:
  Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
  default            192.168.0.254      UGScg             en0       
  127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0       
  127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0       
  169.254            link#6             UCS               en0      !
  192.168.0          link#6             UCS               en0      !
  192.168.0.187/32   link#6             UCS               en0      !  # my macbook
  192.168.0.254/32   link#6             UCS               en0      !  # router
  192.168.0.254      0:1e:e5:6d:91:fb   UHLWIir           en0   1195
  192.168.0.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en0      !
  192.168.56         link#17            UC           vboxnet0      !
  192.168.56.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI       vboxnet0      !
  224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS              en0      !
  224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en0       
  255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS               en0      !
  255.255.255.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en0      !
  ```
- Output of `netstat -rn` with VPN: *(`utun3` are VPN records)*

  ```ini
  Internet:
  Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
  0/1                10.8.0.5           UGScg           utun3       
  default            192.168.0.254      UGScg             en0       
  10.8/24            10.8.0.5           UGSc            utun3     
  10.8.0.1/32        10.8.0.5           UGSc            utun3       
  10.8.0.5           10.8.0.6           UHr             utun3       
  127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0       
  127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0       
  128.0/1            10.8.0.5           UGSc            utun3       
  169.254            link#6             UCS               en0      !
  192.168.0          link#6             UCS               en0      !
  192.168.0.187/32   link#6             UCS               en0      !  # my macbook
  192.168.0.254/32   link#6             UCS               en0      !  # router
  192.168.0.254      0:1e:e5:6d:91:fb   UHLWIir           en0   1162
  192.168.0.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en0      !
  192.168.56         link#17            UC           vboxnet0      !
  192.168.56.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI       vboxnet0      !
  <VPN IP>/32        192.168.0.254      UGSc              en0         # VPN server public IP
  224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS              en0      !
  224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en0       
  255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS               en0      !
  255.255.255.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en0      !
  ```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "But it blocks incoming http(s) traffic from my external IP address. When I turn off OpenVPN I can access my computer from outside, otherwise it is blocked." are you trying to reach a system on the same lan you are on via your ISPs public IP? where are these connections coming from in relation to the target computer? most likely your traffic isn't being blocked, but that you either cannot find the service you are looking for (DNS issues)  or the systems do not have a network path between them because of the VPN gateway and route config.

Comment: Devices in the same LAN can reach my computer without problems.
But as long as OpenVPN is enabled, my computer cannot be reached from my ISP's public IP address. But when I disable OpenVPN, it is reachable from the public IP address. So it is the VPN which is in the way.

Comment: so you have forward ports on your router to your PC, and systems outside your LAN (but not on the other end of the tunnel) are usually able to reach it on 80/443. is that correct?

Comment: My guess is, those systems can contact your PC, but the routing rules are directing your responses into the tunnel, rather than through your routers WAN. can you show us your route table both with and without openvpn connected, and check netstat to make sure your listening ports for 80/443 exist, listen on 0.0.0.0 and are associated with your local webserver process PID.

Comment: How can I show the route table ? I have macOS with homebrew apps.
So how can I configure OpenVPN that when it is on it does not block incoming connections ?
And it is listening to 80 and 443 as local LAN devices can reach it.

Comment: per google,, run `netstat -rn` to display the route table on macos.

Comment: See my own answer, with netstat result.

Comment: The config you provide does not match the resulting routing table. `redirect-gateway def1` is definitely active somehow. // Do you have to redirect everything over the VPN? Or does your office have well-known IP ranges that you could selectively pass through the VPN (so-called split tunneling)?

Comment: @phpandjs The VPN shouldn't be preventing non-VPN access to the endpoint client unless firewall rules aren't correctly configured on the router and/or client _(I'm unsure why the endpoint client would be accessible from WAN to begin with without the use of a VPN, as that implies bypassing the router's stateful firewall which is insecure)_. To allow WAN access in the VPN, uncomment in the server config the two `push "dhcp-option DNS...` lines and LAN access by uncommenting `route <IPsubnet> <Netmask>`, `push "route <IPsubnet> <Netmask>"`, and adding `push "dhcp-option DNS <routerLAN-IP>"`

Comment: @phpandjs _(Cont'd...)_ [Examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN) of these options in a working server and client config

Comment: Daniel B : "Do you have to redirect everything over the VPN? Or does your office have well-known IP ranges that you could selectively pass through the VPN (so-called split tunneling)? " 
Now it redirects everything over the VPN. The server is at the office of my employer. But from that location's public IP address my public IP address is open for ports 80 and 443 to access my computer. And I need the VPN only for outgoing traffic over SSH, HTTP(S) and RDP as most of our customer's servers have an IP filter.
So how can I perform 'split tunneling' ?

Comment: @DanielB `redirect-gateway` must be explicitly enabled in the config, as by default it's disabled _(even if enabled, it would only redirect outgoing traffic to WAN through the VPN, not incoming non-VPN traffic)_. Via the configs provided, the latter can't be caused by the VPN configuration itself and would have to reside in the firewall/networking config of the router, server machine, and/or client. LAN communication with the VPN client requires specifying in, or pushing to, the client config: `route <LAN-IPsubnet> <Netmask>`, `route <LAN-IPsubnet> <Netmask>`, `dhcp-option DNS <routerLAN-IP>`

Comment: plugwash’s answer already addresses why it doesn’t work now. The routing table clearly shows that `redirect-gateway def1` is active (note the _0/1_ and _128/1_ routes). The config presented here is simply not the one in use or at least incomplete.

Comment: I added to the config:

route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.254

and changed 
redirect-gateway def1
to
redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp

but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

It's a routing issue, unfortunately I fear there may not be an easy and satisfactory answer.

Normal IP routing only cares about the destination of a packet, not it's source. In the open internet asymmetric routing is common and not necessarily a problem, but it can become a big problem when NATs, firewalls, ingress filtering etc become involved.

Without the VPN, the client sends packets to your network's NAT router, which modifies the destination address and sends them on to your computer. Your computer then generates a reply, looks up the destination address in it's routing table and sends it back out via your network's NAT router, which performs the reverse translation and puts the packet back out onto the internet where it will be delivered to the client.

When you bring up the VPN your default route is changed to point down the VPN, this means connections you initiate to the internet go down the VPN, but it *also* means that replies to connection requests you receive from the internet go down the VPN.

These replies will almost certainly not be delivered to the client in a usable form. Since the return packets do not pass through the NAT that performed the forward translation, the reverse translation will not be correctly performed. The response packet may be dropped by a filter, it may be forwarded to the client with no reverse translation at all, or it may be forwarded to the client with an incorrect translation. Ultimately the client either doesn't receive the packet at all or receives it with an incorrect source address and is unable to match it up with the connection attempt, either way the attempt to establish a connection fails.